# PHP Syntax error in file when called from Cron Tab

Tags: php, cron

**Edited**

As I guessed, it´s a php version issue:

From command line:

```
php -v
...
PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Mar  1 2012 16:36:14)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
...
```

phpinfo in a web page:

> PHP Version 5.4.20

As far as I know, I won´t be able to change the configuration of the command line version, as it is in a shared server (dreamhost, if it helps someone to a better response).

I really need to use my php 5.3 dependant libraries, replicating some processes from scratch would take me many days of work, and I have to develop this in 2 weeks.

Does someone knows any trick to run a higher version of php than defined for command line?

> I´m having a problem with a Cron Job.
>
> In my project, almost every page includes a file that contains the
>   following lines of code:
>
> ```
> ....
>     $called_class = get_called_class();
>     $this->error_code = 0;
>     $this->error_string = "";
>
>     if ( is_array($parametros) || is_object($parametros) ){
>         foreach ( $parametros as $key => $value ) {
>           if (!$called_class::isValidKey ( $key ) && !$called_class::isExternalKey( $key ) )
>               continue;
>           $this->$key = $value;   
>         }
>     }
> ...
> ```
>
> And never showed me any error.
>
> But when I set a Cron Job to run a script that includes the same file,
>   it sends me the following message to my email:
>
> > Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in
> >     /xxx/xxx/xxx/modelo.php on line 22
>
> What refers to this line:
>
> ```
> if (!$called_class::isValidKey ( $key ) && !$called_class::isExternalKey( $key ) )
> ```
>
> I´m guessing that php version used in command line differs from the
>   one used from the services that shows the page, or whatever it´s
>   called.
>
> I´d appreciate if someone could point me the problem, and suggest me a
>   solution. Btw, I know that I could use a separate file using
>   instructions compatible with previous versions of php for the cron
>   job, but I´d like to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, what you're suspecting seems to be the case. Have you checked `sudo php -v` from the command line?

Comment: It´s a shared server, and I do not have permissions to run sudo command, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely caused by running the script in the wrong working directory, try changing your crontab command to:

```
cd path/to/script/directory && php script.php
```

Comment: Although I´m pretty sure that it´s not a problem with the working directory, I tried to do as you said from the command line with the same error.

Is there usually any place where I can change command line php version? If so, how is it usually called?

Answer (score 1):

Ok... seems to be so easy that I feel a bit ashamed.

changed the command:

> /usr/local/bin/php

for

> /usr/local/php54/bin/php

That´s for my dreamhost server, but may be similar in other shared servers.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: +1 for figuring it out yourself when noone could really help!